# Efficient way to convert <dattm.dt> to date in R

Tags: python, r, reticulate

Here is my issue:
I am using reticulate to source python data frames from a database. One of the variables is in a date format. When I do the conversion from python to R, the date variable gets transformed into a list object and all the entries show as <dattm.dt> (see dput below):
I have been dealing with the problem as follows:

```
library(tidyverse);library(reticulate); library(lubridate)

date_strings <- x %>% pull(date_object) ##Retrieve the date listt
fixed_dates <- sapply(1:length(date_strings), function(j){
        p <- py_to_r(date_strings[[j]])
        return(p)} %>% as_date() ##Apply function to fix each entry individually

##Dput below
structure(list(date_object = list(<environment>, <environment>, 
    <environment>, <environment>, <environment>, <environment>, 
    <environment>, <environment>, <environment>, <environment>, 
    <environment>, <environment>, <environment>, <environment>, 
    <environment>, <environment>, <environment>, <environment>, 
    <environment>, <environment>), metric = c(0.216754862863576, 
-0.542492572263425, 0.891144645072327, 0.595980577187475, 1.63561800111297, 
0.689275441919723, -1.28124663010116, -0.213144519278363, 1.89653987190927, 
1.77686321368272, 0.566604498180317, 0.01571945400457, 0.383057338517151, 
-0.0451371159133086, 0.0343519073969926, 0.169026774218306, 1.16502683902767, 
-0.0442039972520874, -0.100368442585905, -0.283444568873591)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), pandas.index = <environment>)
```

Here are the top elements of the date_strings object:

```
[[1]]
<environment: 0x7f904dc4d5b8>
attr(,"class")
[1] "datetime.date"         "python.builtin.object"

[[2]]
<environment: 0x7f904dc4d430>
attr(,"class")
[1] "datetime.date"         "python.builtin.object"

[[3]]
<environment: 0x7f904dc4d318>
attr(,"class")
[1] "datetime.date"         "python.builtin.object"
```

While this approach works well for small datasets, it takes a really long time when the data frame is big (think thousands of rows). Is there a way to optimize the process or to vectorize it?

Comment: Your `dput` shows environment.  Can you get the `dput` after the `return(p)`

Comment: Or may be get the `dput` of `py_to_r(date_strings[1])`

Comment: Added dput below the code snippet Let me know if this fixed the problem

Comment: For some reason your current dput is also not usable as it returns the enviornment

Comment: Is there a workaround or should I delete the question?

Comment: I am not sure whether you are using `py_to_r` in a correct way.  The code `date_strings <- x %>% pull(date_object)` seems to be `R` based and why you are using `py_to_r` here

Comment: `py_to_r` is used when you have a python struvture and wnats to convert to `R` i.e. `a <- np$array(c(1:4));
sum <- a$cumsum();


py_to_r(sum)`

Comment: The variable in the data frame is definitely a python variable. I use py_to_r to cast it as an R object and then convert it into date.

Comment: then your `date` objects are not retrieved correctly

Comment: Instead of `sapply` use `lapply` as `sapply` can cause some issues by coercion

Comment: Can you show `date_strings[1:5]`

Comment: First elements added

Comment: that is also not helpful as it is an environemnt value.  Try with `lapply` .e. `lapply(seq_along(date_strings),  function(j) py_to_r(date_strings[[j]]))` and check the output if it is converted to `R` or not

Comment: Yep, all R dates

Comment: Then try `do.call(c, lapply(seq_along(date_strings),  function(j) py_to_r(date_strings[[j]])))`

Comment: Also worked. Returned a vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `lapply` instead of `sapply` and convert to a `vector` with `c` using `do.call`.  The reason is that if the evaluated dates are `Date` class`,` c` will not coerce it to integer mode

```
do.call(c, lapply(seq_along(date_strings), 
        function(j) py_to_r(date_strings[[j]])))
```